# Coverity OpenSource Scan: Failed to retrieve tar file

Tags: coverity

We are trying to use the Coverity OpenSource service but have problems submitting our project files for analyses.

Whenever submitting the *project*.tgz  to the coverity (no matter whether this is done via the automation instruction or via the website directly),
we  see that the build is being queued for a short time:

> *Last Build Status: Running. Your build is currently being analyzed*

But after a few second the build fails as it cannot find the archive:

> *Last Build Status: Failed. Your build has failed due to the following reason. Please fix the error and upload the build again.
>   Error details: :Failed to retrieve tar file ...more*

The build log seems fine:

> ```
> 2015-12-18T12:30:44.458433Z|cov-build|5752|info|> Build time (cov-build overall): 00:34:26.499117
> 2015-12-18T12:30:44.458433Z|cov-build|5752|info|> 
>
> 2015-12-18T12:30:44.462750Z|cov-build|5752|info|> Build time (C/C++/Java emits total): 00:49:03.604351
>
> 2015-12-18T12:30:44.462750Z|cov-build|5752|info|> 
>
> 2015-12-18T12:30:44.462750Z|cov-build|5752|info|> 
>
> 2015-12-18T12:30:44.462794Z|cov-build|5752|info|> 397 C/C++ compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis
>
> 2015-12-18T12:30:44.462794Z|cov-build|5752|info|> 19 Java compilation units (100%) have been captured and are ready for analysis
> ```

The issue seems to be consistent with [Error details: :Failed to download tar file from](https://communities.coverity.com/thread/3508) . Unfortunately, there is no solution.

Is there any naming convention/and or size restriction for the archive?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: ***"Failed to retrieve tar file..."*** - It fails the same way if you upload a ZIP, too. I'm fairly certain the service is broken since we used to be able to upload a build. But we've been experiencing the same error for about six weeks now. Also see [How to troubleshoot build-failure notification received from Coverity SCAN](https://communities.coverity.com/message/4820) on Coverity's site and [“Last Build Status: Failed” after uploading a build for analysis](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34489826) on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Last Build Status: Failed" after uploading a build for analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489826/last-build-status-failed-after-uploading-a-build-for-analysis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting the coverity support we just received the following answer and we could successfully submit a build. Seems there was some hickup on the coverity side.

> "This was due to some behind the
>   scenes issues on our end – nothing interesting,, but it is back up and
>   running now. Thanks for your patience".

Comment: I had a successful scan a few hours ago, but now the error is back!