# "Last Build Status: Failed" after uploading a build for analysis

Tags: coverity

We use Coverity's free [scanning service](https://scan.coverity.com/projects/cryptopp) for free and open source projects. We have not been able to utilize the service for the last two months or so. Prior to the service failures, we had half-a-dozen or so good analysis.

Submitting a scan results in:

> Last Build Status: Failed. Your build has failed due to the following reason. Please fix the error and upload the build again.
>   Error details: :Failed to retrieve tar file

Coverity is very good about providing copy/paste directions, and we have copied/pasted them religiously. We verified there are no build errors, and we verified the build ends with ***"131 C/C++ compilation units (100%) are ready for analysis"*** and ***"The cov-build utility completed successfully"***.

We've tried to resolve the issue by verifying things from [this generic solution](https://communities.coverity.com/message/4820) provided in a "failed email" response from the service. We verified or performed all of them except number four.

We did not perform number four because Coverity's documentation is horrible (its the exact opposite of their awesome scanning service). Because there's no instructions or RTFM to read, we have no idea which knobs should be turned for `bin/cov-configure`. We don't want to mess with it since it worked in the past.

We also tried the following:

- using the web submission form and browser
- using curl from the command line
- packaging ***`cov-int/`*** in a tarball
- packaging ***`cov-int/`*** in a zip file
- using all lowercase for the project name
- capitalizing the first letter of the project name

We always get the same message (***"Failed to retrieve tar file"***), even with a ZIP file. Recall that prior to about 6 weeks ago, everything was working fine.

What is the secret to uploading a file to the service? What has changed in the last six weeks or two months?

Comment: We emailed support and opened a ticket.: ***`Case# 00538992: Coverity service for free/open source projects is not working as expected`***. We did *not* ask for help with just our project. We asked for help for all free/open source projects in a similar situation.

Comment: I just got the following response: "This was due to some behind the scenes issues on our end – nothing interesting,, but it is back up and running now.
Thanks for your patience". Seems to work right work right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After contacting the coverity support we just received the following answer and we could successfully submit a build. Seems there was some hickup on the coverity side.

> "This was due to some behind the
>   scenes issues on our end – nothing interesting,, but it is back up and
>   running now. Thanks for your patience".